# Is it possible to reuse API Platform/Symfony generated model definitions through @groups?

Tags: symfony, swagger, api-platform.com

Currently on mine API Platform service, I've created several endpoints for same entity and I am using @Groups to filter the attributes to be returned.
I noticed that Swagger documentation is being automatically generated based on this @Groups definitions and it is creating one model for each endpoint - or each group combination.

The problem raises when I convert the Swagger definition to TypeScript interfaces, because it is generating a lot of similar interfaces.

I'd like to know if it possible to reuse the same model definition among the several endpoints, and flag which attribute is required or not to each one of them.

Thanks in advance, guys

Answer (score 0):

Answer: There is no way to define which interface you want to generate / filter, that seems like a feature to add to the generator.

BTW, I think you are missunderstanding the purpouse of Groups.

You can use a Filter that applies a Group to filter attributes instead of having multiple endpoints. Ex: `GET products?groups[]=READ&groups[]=GROUP_ADMIN&groups[]=CLIENT`

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#group-filter